# Continuous functions on Closed/Bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Ok so I know that if K is closed and bounded, f(K) is also closed and bounded, I reckon both statements are false but not entirely sure, I just cant seem to come up with counter examples. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample for closed: consider the set $S:=(x,1/x)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ , and consider $f(x):=\pi_2(x)$ which is the projection to the second component (into $\mathbb R$). 
Then $\pi_2(S)=\mathbb R-{0}$ , which is open, since it is the complement in $\mathbb R$ of the closed set {$0$}.

For the second case, consider the function $f(x)=1/x$ on the bounded set $(0,1)$. $f$ is continuous there, but grows without bound.

And, for completeness, here is an example of how the continuous image of an open set is not necessarily open: take the open interval $(-1,1)$ ( take it, please!) , and the continuous function $f(x)=x^2$. Then {$f(-1,1)$}=$[0,1)$ , which is not open.

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example f(bounded)= not bounded:

$$\tan\left(\left]-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right[\right)=\Bbb R$$

counter-example: f(closed)=non closed:

$$\arctan(\Bbb R)= \left]-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right[$$